# DATEDIFF Incorrect results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my code and the result is 1 but it must be 0 because the duration is not a full minute

```
DECLARE @Start AS DATETIME = '2013-10-08 09:12:59.000'
DECLARE @End AS DATETIME   = '2013-10-08 09:13:09.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MI,@Start, @End)
```

How can I work around this issue?
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Update**

It works fine with the seconds.....just not the minutes.

```
DECLARE @Start AS DATETIME = '2013-10-08 09:12:59.000'
DECLARE @End AS DATETIME   = '2013-10-08 09:13:09.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(SS,@Start, @End)
```

Comment: [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx): "Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart **boundaries crossed** between the specified startdate and enddate." (My emphasis) Between your startdate and enddate, you cross the minute boundary from 09:12 to 09:13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Start AS DATETIME = '2013-10-08 09:12:59.000'
DECLARE @End AS DATETIME   = '2013-10-08 09:13:09.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(SS,@Start, @End)/60
```

Comment: `2013-10-08 09:12:59.997` and `2013-10-08 09:13:59.000` still isn't a full minute and this returns `1`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree with you. Furthermore this solution will also cause an overflow error if the start is 1900 and end is today

Comment: @MartinSmith: Not sure why you said or if he had changed it but as per it now, [this does not return 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22747)

Comment: @Kaf - You aren't using the values I mentioned in my comment. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22754)

Answer (score 3):

DATEDIFF is quite simple and if you compare minutes, it won't take seconds into account.

Change your query to get the difference in seconds and divide it by 60, rounding down.

Comment: Weird, the seconds do take the minutes into account.

Answer (score 2):

9:12 to 9:13 = 1 minute

if you want better resolution, use seconds (`SS`) for your datepart then divide by 60

Answer (score 2):

As @MartinSmith mentioned, the current solutions are not handling milliseconds, here is a more exact method

```
declare @t table(date1 datetime, date2 datetime)
insert @t values('2013-10-08 09:12:00', '2013-10-08 09:13:59')
insert @t values('2013-10-08 09:12:30', '2013-10-08 09:13:29')
insert @t values('2013-10-08 09:12:30:111', '2013-10-08 09:13')
insert @t values('2013-10-08 09:12:30:111', '2013-10-08 09:13')
insert @t values('2013-10-08 09:12:30', '2013-10-08 09:12')

select case when date2 > date1 
        then datediff(minute, 0, date2-date1)
        else -datediff(minute, 0, date1 - date2) 
       end
from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise you can use:

```
DECLARE @Start AS DATETIME = '2013-10-08 09:12:59.997'
DECLARE @End AS DATETIME   = '2013-10-08 09:13:59.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MS,@Start, @End)/60000.00
```

But you should be aware, that difference between '2013-10-08 09:12:59.001' and '2013-10-08 09:13:59.000' will be in this case also 1.

Comment: try START = '2013-10-08', END = '2013-11-08'. Result will be overflow